# Angular/Ionic -- Why is my function calling every time I type in an input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm trying to teach myself how to build an Angular/Ionic app. I'm using Backand to store JSON, and I'm hoping to call a random JSON value each time the page reloads.

Right now, the random call function calls every time I type in an input. I'm unclear why this is happening.

index.html

```
<label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" placeholder="New Todo" ng-model="input.name">
</label>
<div>
  <p class="challenge-text">
       {{challenges[randomChallenge(challenges.length)].name}}
  </p>
</div>
```

app.js

```
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, ViewChallenges) {
  $scope.challenges = [];
  $scope.suggested = [];
  $scope.input={};
  $scope.randomChallenge = function(length){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
}

  function getAllChallenges() {
    ViewChallenges.getChallenges()
    .then(function (result) {
      $scope.challenges = result.data.data;
    });
  }

  $scope.suggestChallenge = function(){
      ViewChallenges.suggestChallenge($scope.input)
      .then(function(result){
          $scope.input = {};
          getAllChallenges();
      })
  }



  getAllChallenges();

})

.service('ViewChallenges', function ($http, Backand) {
  var baseUrl = '/1/objects/';
  var challenges = 'challenges/';
  var suggestedChallenge = 'suggested/'

  function getUrl(x) {
    return Backand.getApiUrl() + baseUrl + x;
  };


  getChallenges = function () {
    return $http.get(getUrl(challenges));
  };

  suggestChallenge = function(suggested){
      return $http.post(getUrl(suggestedChallenge), suggested)
  }


  return {
    getChallenges: getChallenges,
    suggestChallenge: suggestChallenge
  }
});
```

Comment: really bad idea to have a function in view that returns random values due to the way angular digest cycles work. Assign to a variable once in the controller

Answer (score 0):

It is because `input.name` changes everytime you change the input.

This in turn changes `randomChallenge(challenges.length)` which is a method.

So each time you change the input the output `{{challenges[randomChallenge(challenges.length)].name}}` gets affected.

Comment: Could you explain why input.name changes each time I type in the input? I'm basing my project off this tutorial: https://devdactic.com/ionic-backend-database/, and it doesn't really explain conceptually what's going on very well.